# What does the [0] signify in len(a[0])?

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops, parameters

So I have this code which I found out but I am unable to understand what is the function of the [0] or any number in fact here.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [[6,3],[5,9]]
t = [[0,0],[0,0]]

for i in range(len(a)):

    for j in range(len(b[0])):

        for k in range(len(b)):
             t[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
print t
```

I am really new to python so, sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: The first element of the list... a subscript

Comment: Look up list indexing, subscripting and/or `__getitem__`. `[0]` grabs the first element of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the things you don't understand (and read the docs while you go).

Given

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [[6,3],[5,9]]
t = [[0,0],[0,0]]
```

we get

```
>>> len(a)
2
```

So, `a` has two things in, which we can access by indexing into `a`
And we'll get an error if we go too far:

```
>>> a[0]
[1, 2]
>>> a[1]
[3, 4]
>>> a[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You asked about `len(a[0])`, though the code says `len(b[0])`.
`a[0]` was `[1, 2]`, so a list of two things, and indeed

```
>>> len(a[0])
2
```

or even

```
>>> len(b[0])
2
```

You have some lists of lists. Indexing into them will give you a single list back.

And just to recap, `a[0]` is a list `[1,2]`. We can get either element of that, and if we go too far we get an error:

```
>>> a[0][0]
1
>>> a[0][1]
2
>>> a[0][2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

The code is doing matrix multiplication, see what you get for `t`:

```
>>> print t
[[16, 21], [38, 45]]
```

[image: As matrix]

You could regard each list of lists as part of a matrix, with the first index giving the row and the second the column:

[image: rows and columns]

Comment: Yeah, I know that it does matrix multiplication :). Thanks a lot for taking your time and answering :)

Answer (score 0):

When `a` is a list, `a[0]` will return the first element of `a` (lists begin at 0).
In your case, `a[0]=[1,2]`, `b[0]=[6,3]`, `b[1]=[5,9]`, and `a[0][0]=1`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question :)